# Curved Buttons Don't Work In Emulator, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It's a strange one this that I've been trying to solve on and off for a couple of days. I made the xml file for the round_buttons and put the @drawable in the code for each button. They all show up fine in Android Studio on the preview but in the emulator the curved button works on my first screen but on the 2nd it doesn't.

This is what it looks like on the preview and exactly how I'd like it to look.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR8XD.png)

This is how it looks in the emulator or when I test it on my phone.

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yiE3.png)

When I create a new button the the screen I'm having difficulty with for some reason it curves but those 4 I can't get to curve at all and I have no idea why. This is my first app and I realise I'm probably missing something completely stupid.

Here is my code for one of the buttons that won't work in the emulator.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer 2"
    android:id="@+id/answerButton2"
    android:textColor="#fc0000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/answerButton3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/answerButton1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/answerButton1" />
```

And the code for my button that works on the first screen and also works in the other screen if I randomly put it in there.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Quiz"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:id="@+id/startQuizButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:textColor="#fc0000"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

If anyone has any idea what the hell I'm doing wrong here it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Update:

round_button.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: what is round_button? is it a png? a 9-patch? an xml drawable? if it's an xml drawable, please post the code for it.

Comment: Yeah it's an xml drawable. I've updated it with the code, I've tried all kinds of different things with the xml and I just can't get it to work. Works with any other button I create except those 4. It works with those 4 in the preview screen but when I run the actual app the buttons are still normal rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this draws an orange button, you might be able to use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#FFA500"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#FFA500"
    />
</shape>
```

Here is the xml of the button:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignOut"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageTop"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageTop"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:text="Sign Out"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_btn_shape"
    />
```